# How do I fix this cv2.imshow() syntax error?

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I cannot get the following code to run:

```
import cv2 # import Open Cv moudle
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import matplotlib as plt

imgEloun=face_recognition.load_image_file  ("image/elounMask.jpg")        # load Image
imgEloun=cv2.cvtColor(imgEloun,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)      # changing BGR clr to RGB

imgTest=face_recognition.load_image_file ("image/steve jobs.jpg")    # Load Image
imgTest=cv2.cvtColor(imgTest,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)    # changing BGR clr to RGB

faceLocation=face_recognition.face_locations(imgEloun)[0]  #Detect face loaction in image
encodeELOUN=face_recognition.face_encodings(imgEloun)[0]  #encoding face location
cv2.rectangle(imgEloun,(faceLocation[3],(faceLocation[0]),(faceLocation[1],(faceLocation[2]),(255,0,255))

cv2.imshow('elounMask',imgEloun)   ######## here is error
cv2.imshow('steve jobs',imgTest)      # Show Image as output
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwARQ.png) of my error in PyCharm.

Is anyone able to help out?

Comment: Are you missing one or more parentheses at line 17?

Comment: Please post your code [not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please use the code tags to paste your code in your question.

Comment: add `)` at the end of the `cv2.rectangle`

Answer (score 0):

```
cv2.rectangle(imgEloun,((faceLocation[3],(faceLocation[0])),((faceLocation[1],(faceLocation[2])),(255,0,255))
```

you missed the parenthesis when giving the coordinates for rectangle. It should be in this format,
eg: `cv2.rectangle(image, (5,5), (200,200), (255,255,0), 2)`